# Имя сказочного персонажа

Tags: орфография, ономастика

Как правильно - Золотая рыбка или Золотая Рыбка? Речь идет не о породе аквариумных рыбок, а именно о сказочном персонаже, исполняющем желания. Насчет того, что "Золотая" с большой буквы, у меня как-то сомнений не возникает. А что насчет "рыбки"?

Answer (score 4):

Правильно: Золотая Рыбка. А также: Дед Мороз, Красная Шапочка, Серый Волк, Змей Горыныч - в составных именах действующих лиц в художественной литературе, в том числе сказках, обе буквы прописные.

Также для сравнения: Екатерина Великая, Иван Грозный, Елена Прекрасная, Владимир Красное Солнышко - все слова пишутся с прописной буквы. Это объясняется тем, что каждое слово в именах и прозвищах является условным, ИНДИВИДУАЛЬНЫМ названием.

Для сравнения: Куликовская битва, Политехнический музей, Сретенский бульвар - здесь только ПЕРВОЕ слово в составном имени собственном пишется с прописной буквы, а остальные имеют РЕАЛЬНОЕ, а не условное значение.

Comment: Ну, положим, рыбка -- это тоже вполне реальное значение, она же правда рыбка, а не креветка какая-нибудь:)

Comment: Это рыбка, которую зовут Золотой Рыбкой: рыбка Золотая Рыбка, приложение + имя собственное. Такое правило относится ко всем лицам, а также персонажам, действующим в литературе. Для сравнения:тюльпан Махровый ранний (спец.). В этом случае тюльпан - это приложение, а Махровый ранний - имя собственное, в котором только первое слово пишется с прописной буквы, а второе имеет реальное значение.